# accessing custom asset at a runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I'm working on an app, which generates custom css files (compiles the scss at the run time) and places them in `/public/asset/themes` folder. When I want to access the generated files, for instance `/public/assets/themes/1.css` by calling the following code:

```
Rails.Application.assets["themes/1.css"]
```

I get nil (no response), even though my paths are added with:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('public','themes')
```

When I want to access other files, which are generated by Sprockets, it works fine.

Why am I unable to access the files with this approach?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Add custom folder as below:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "theme")
```

Now to see the added paths in Terminal you can use either of the below given options:

`y Rails.application.config.assets.paths` OR `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

If you need to call the respective stylesheet, then call it as below;

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "1" %> (for 1.css)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The css file I generate is not in app/assets folder but in public/assets. So should that work?

Comment: Are you in production mode?

Comment: Currently in dev, why?

Comment: Then you can add assets through `app/assets` OR `lib/assets` OR `vendor/assets` only. `public/assets` is a default location for precompiled assets only and we will never do precompilation in Development mode. Did you read asset pipeline reference in railsguides?

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it really helped you and for future reference also.